# How to uncheck checkbox before change() event is triggered

Tags: jquery

I have lots of input fields in my form and on every field change serialized form data is sent to the server.

Now I need to prevent some check-boxes to be selected (can't use `"disabled"` attribute, `alert()` has to be triggered when clicked on these check-boxes).

I tried it with binding to `click()` event, but it looks like `change()` event is triggered before `click()` and serialized data is sent as if check-box was selected.

Now I'm trying with `mousedown()` event, but `prop('checked', false)` doesn't seem to be working and actually has the opposite effect - check-box ends up always checked.

Here is JsFiddle test case - http://jsfiddle.net/F8x2X/19/

So how do I uncheck check-box before `change()` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a class on the checkboxes that should not be checked and make a check in the change event

```
Foo: <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class='notcheck' value="1" /><br/>

<div id="result"></div>

$(':input').change(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('notcheck')){
       alert('you can\'t check this   !');
        $(this).removeProp('checked');
       return;

    }
    var data = $(':input').serialize();
    var checked = '';

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checked = 'Yes';
    } else {
        checked = 'No';
    }

    $('#result').append('Checked: ' + checked + '; Serialized: ' + data + '<br/>');
});
```

fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/F8x2X/20/

Comment: Thanks for your help, getting closer. I removed `return;` statement from your example, because I still want other form data to be sent. Now it looks like `serialize()` is not serializing check-box anymore, but if you check click on the check-box again, it looks like it gets checked anyway on every other click - http://jsfiddle.net/F8x2X/22/

Comment: Ok, I replaced your `removeProp('checked')` with `prop('checked', false)` and it's working fine now. Final result - http://jsfiddle.net/F8x2X/25/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `confirm` to check with the user if they are sure they want to deselect a checkbox, for example:

```
$('input.record_age').on('change', function(e) {
  $this = $(this);
  if(!$this.prop('checked')) { // only when unchecked
    confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to stop recording age?");
    if(!confirmed) { $this.prop('checked', true) } // if they press Cancel, change back to checked, otherwise leave as is.
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I get the question, but is this it : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/F8x2X/23/)

```
var data = $(':input').prop('checked', false).serialize();
```

Comment: No, some check-boxes and radio boxes can be checked, so I can't disable all of them.